# How to get specific date based upon current year in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Can someone tell me how to get specific date based upon current year in SSRS report parameters.

ex: if current year is 2016 I want date field to populate as 31-Dec-2014,
if current year is 2017 then it should be 31-Dec-2015,
if current year is 2018 then it should be 31-Dec-2016, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=DateSerial(Today.Year-2,12,31)
```

Let me know if this helps.